# UI in QGIS for a UML class with multiple cardinality attribute

Tags: qgis, postgis, uml

For example: a "way" class with a name[1:n] attribute. Mapping the UML class to SQL you can get something like:

```
create table way
(
   id serial not null primary key,
   geom geometry,
   other_attribute text
)

create table way_name
(
   way_id integer not null,
   name text not null,
   foreign key (way_id) references way (id) on update cascade on delete cascade,
   primary key way_name_pkey (way_id, name)
)
```

QGIS can automatic discovers the relationship between tables and you can set up a form for the "parent" entity (way) and include a subform-relation for the names. But it seems that creating a new way is a 2-step process in QGIS because when I edit a new way I can´t set its name. I have to close/accept the form, 
save layers changes, open the form again and (now that the way exists in the database) set the way name. Is there any solution for 1-step new features editing?

Obviously, I can do it if no foreign key exists but I can lost the relational integrity.

Comment: I'd always prefer to implement in-DB entry points for (multi)relational tables, i.e. *Views*, that centralize the rerouting of any data manipulation. makes the data model consistent and easy to maintain, and handles any client application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you properly stated, the problem is, that there is no primary key created on the parent table (way), so no children (way_name) can be added.

To overcome this issue, QGIS offers a project wide setting **Evaluate default values server side**. This will pre-create properly defined default values in the form before it is saved.

See the data source [section of the documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/qgis_configuration.html#data-sources-properties).

Be aware, that you will need to save the parent (way) layer first (because the database will complain if you add children (way_names) referencing non existent objects).

There is a second option **create transaction groups** which will automatically make all layers from the same database editable at the same time and create a transaction. If the **foreign keys are [configured as deferred](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html)** this will allow creating children before their parents and the referential integrity will only be checked at the end of the transaction (commit / save layer in QGIS).